# Turning off logging for Until-Successful in mule

Tags: mule

Until successful logs can be really noisy, throwing line after line of the following:

```
 Exception thrown inside until-successful Failure expression positive when processing event: MuleEvent: 0-5af41671-38b9-11e6-9268-0e9420524153, stop processing=false, vm://dropForCanvas
```

Does anyone know of a quick way to turn off this kind of logging in Mule.  I've had similar experiences with splitters that return nothing.  These entries fill up my logs in some apps.

Comment: I have similar scenario, did you find anything helpful to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can override config at the domain or application level. When an application is deployed, Mule looks for a config file following a child-first pattern, as listed below:

- Look for a file called log4j2-test.xml in the application classpath
- Look for a file called log4j2.xml in the application classpath
- Look for a file called log4j2-test.xml in the domain classpath
- Look for a file called log4j2.xml in the domain classpath
- Look for a file called log4j2-test.xml in MULE_HOME/conf
- Look for a file called log4j2.xml in MULE_HOME/conf
- Apply default configuration.

Check below link for same
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/logging-in-mule#sts=Logging in Mule

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the configuration to org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy to FATAL (via the Log4j configuration)